# file JS untracked on React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, visual-studio-code, frontend

I got this error when creating functional component i got this error:
[image]

the error said cannot find dile Buku.js .\src\components\Buku\Buku.Js'. but the JS file what i imported is exist and i'm sure not write wrong directory
[image]

Comment: Please see [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question). Did you try renaming `Buku.Js` to `Buku.js`? Please show the file where you're importing Buku (App.js, as text).

Comment: remove .js from Buku.js  .\src\components\Buku\Buku

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the below solutions:

Rename: `Buku.Js to Buku.js`

Also:  remove js from Buku.js `.\src\components\Buku\Buku`